# Differences between symlink to /tmp and tmpfs

Tags: linux, mount, symbolic-link, fstab, tmpfs

I'm trying to make a read-only file-system (Raspbian). One common way is to place some directory (that are to be writable) in a tmpfs.

Example, I found some tutorials that suggest:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dhcp/ /var/run /var/spool /var/lock
ln -s /tmp /var/lib/dhcp
ln -s /tmp /var/run
ln -s /tmp /var/spool
ln -s /tmp /var/lock
```

and in `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
```

as far as I understand:

- `/var/lib/dhcp/`, `/var/run`, `/var/spool` and `/var/lock` are symlinked to `/tmp` that is mounted as tmpfs
- but `/var/log` and `/var/tmp` are mounted on separated tmpfs

Why you can't mount just `/tmp` as tmpfs and symlink there all the other directories?

Comment: Strange technique... normally non-root users can write to /tmp but not to /var/log or /var/run. With the links above writing to /tmp is the same as writing to these directories. Still access rights or avoiding name clashes could be an explanation.

Comment: It makes sense. About the "strange" technique - would you mind to suggest a better one?

Comment: As far as a I can tell, one could make separate directories under `/tmp/` (or even to be cleaner `/tmp/var`) and link each `/var/something` to the matching `/tmp/var/something` (with adequate access rights).

Comment: Ok, that was I tried to say with *Why you can't mount just /tmp as tmpfs and symlink there all the other directories?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no one true correct approach, one of the better ones is the one [suggested by xenoid](https://superuser.com/questions/1247525/differences-between-symlink-to-tmp-and-tmpfs#comment1830893_1247525): mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs` and make subdirectories there with the appropriate permissions. Then link the appropriate subdirectories of `/var` to those.

In general, it's probably not a good idea to mount multiple temporary file systems unless you manually specify their size. By default (according to `man tmpfs`), each will get half the amount of RAM available. Your example would use up a total of 87.5% of whatever the free memory is at time of mounting, and each successive instance is half the size of the previous one. This is a profoundly strange thing to do.

As an alternative, if you truly only want a temporary file system, you could make a single large `tmpfs` and use [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) or something similar to make a writeable temporary overlay of `/`. The possible safety you lose in having a fundamentally writeable `/` (with permissions providing the usual amount of security anyway) is offset by the whole thing being cleared on reboot.